# 本番サーバー(Linux)のGitを GUIクライアントで見たい

Tags: git

本番サーバー(Linux)のGitをGUIクライアントで見たいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Comment: ローカルに `clone` してしまえば、サーバ側が何であるかはあまり重要ではなく、GUIクライアントを実行したい方の情報の方が必要なのかなと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。本番へはgit pull orign masterが基本ではあるのですが、しかっり、ログツリーを確認したりを本番サーバー自体でもしたいと思いまして、GUIで何か出来ないかと思っているところです

Comment: GUIクライアントを実行するのが、本番サーバ(Linux)上なのか、それ以外のOSなのかを質問文に含めて欲しいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
説明不足でした、実はこのやり方はやっていまして、サーバーのスペックとGit管理ファイルが少ない際には有効なのですが、
(作業コピーをローカルにキャッシュして、そのデータをローカル内でGit処理しているため)
イメージとしては、本番サーバー内のGitで処理して、それをローカルの画面に表示するだけみたいなやり方があればと思ってるところなんです。xwindowというのを知ってはいるのですが、本番サーバーにGUIを入れてもOKか(スペックの消費・不安定になるため、入れるべきではないのか)？などが気になっています

Answer (score 0):

可能かどうかはネットワーク構成次第です。CUIでもGUIでも。ふつう本番環境に直接アクセスできないようにするでしょうから、間に中継サーバでも入れないと難しいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。小規模なサイトなので、本番へSSHで直接アクセスできる形です